# How Can I Publish My App on Test Flight For Development Target?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm sending my app's new version that builds for production target to testers on Test Flight before release.
I also want to send my app to testers on Test Flight that build for development target. I need this because before release rest api's new version I want to be sure everything works well. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the build for different targets. Create a build with Dev environment REST API's links and publish it on Testflight with your testers and same case for Production environment. 
You can have these settings in your .plist to manage the REST API's for your different environment.

Comment: Ok but I already know this and do this. I want to publish that archive on test flight without override prod app. I think it's not possible without change bundleID

Comment: You can upload a another archive with the same bundleID but with the updated build version. Then you'll have two builds there.

Comment: Yes but then I should increase version for every dev target publish.

Comment: Yes, you should increase the version whenever you publish a new build. Its a good process to follow, as it will make easier to keep track of the different builds.